# How to replace a band (hub, drum) brake with a freewheel

Tags: gears, freewheel, axle, freehub, band-brake

I am looking to convert my bicycle into a semi-electric bike by adding a freewheel. The 2 freewheels will allow me to use either pedals or an electric motor to move the bike. However, I don't have enough space on the right side where the current freewheel is positioned. Therefore, I want to remove the current band brake on the left side
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
and replace it with a freewheel.

I have researched and watched a few videos, but I am still uncertain how to remove the current band brake because they look a little different from mine (I think mine is a Shimano roller break which looks like a combination of hub break and drum break_. Can you please advise me on which tools to use, and if possible, provide a video tutorial?

Also, I am not sure how to install the freewheel once I have removed the band brake. What do I need to add to host the freewheel in place? Do I need to reverse the freewheel side because it is on the opposite side of the bicycle?

Thank you.

Comment: Additiona question, how do you add a brake to the rear?   Going with one brake on any bike is a bad idea, one brake on a heavier powered electric bike is even worse.  You need a rear brake that works.

Comment: I think I can use Cantilever brake, V-brake, or dual caliper brake, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add an additional freewheel to the existing solid bicycle axle?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/92350/how-can-i-add-an-additional-freewheel-to-the-existing-solid-bicycle-axle)

Comment: @DavidW It's the same person asking both questions.

Comment: @Michaelcomelately I get that; that's why I voted to close as duplicate.  (The message is automatic.)  It looks like the same answer would answer both.

Comment: @DavidW this version is asking specifically about removing the band brake and replacing that with a freewheel, whereas the other question is about stacking two freewheels on the right-hand side of the wheel.  So absolutely related, but still different

Comment: I think Criggie got the main point, but I also appreciate @DavidW for pointing it out. To clarify, my question on the other link is open to many options and also involves asking about how to adapt the freewheel to the axle. I'm not really inclined to remove the brake option in that scenario while this question is seriously considering removing the brake if that is truly a good choice.

Comment: In the photos it looks like the brake is already on left side. Also, I'm not sure if we should encourage projects like this.

Comment: I can add in another break as mentioned in my previous post, what is your concern @ojs ?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea on how to remove the break and replace it with a freewheel? Or could you suggest a place where I could ask this question to find the answer? Thank you very much!